# setinitial text showing null for twitter

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5

I am implementing Twitter integration in my app. But setintialtext showing empty dialog box.

My code is:

```
TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetSheet = 
        [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
        if ([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet])
        {

NSString *tw=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"AT %@ %@ \n on %@\n %@ %@ %@ vs %@",lbl_vanueName.text,lbl_address.text,[arr_eventDate objectAtIndex:0],[arr_eventName objectAtIndex:0],[arr_EventType objectAtIndex:0],[arr_Contestant1 objectAtIndex:0],[arr_Contestant2 objectAtIndex:0]] retain];
            NSLog(@" tw is:%@",tw); // work fine & got all values

           [tweetSheet setInitialText:tw];
             }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the return value of the `setInitialText` method. If you check the docs for `TWTweetComposeViewController`, there is a comment:

**Return Value**

YES if successful. NO if text does not fit in the currently available character space or the view was presented to the user.

*Maybe the text doesn't fit?*